# Magento 2 Category Search id issue

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, advanced-search

I have getting some error display in console but category search page is working properly and this error comes every time in console if any one know regarding this error reply me.[image]

Comment: Inspect your page, ans see all these 3 elements are coming 3 times. That's an issue from js point of view.

Comment: I know but where i go to debug

Comment: Try enabling temple path hint for files. They must be coming due to some ajax functionality. Which is replacing content.